# How to keep GCP Secret Manager and AWS Secret Manager in sync using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, terraform, aws-secrets-manager, google-secret-manager

I have an app that utilizes both AWS and GCP Secret Managers, and this app is deployed through Terraform.

Is it possible/is it a good idea to have Terraform keep these in sync.

For example, if I need to change my database password, can I change the secret in GCP, deploy via Terraform and have those secrets copied over to AWS Secret Manager, which can then be accessed from the Lambda Functions I deploy?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to replicate secret. Having them in one place is better. Having them in another cloud provider is not a problem because you should not have latency issue with the secret (you do not access them frequently).

Comment: Instead of having a bi-directional sync, I would recommend storing the secrets in a central location, and then syncing out to each secrets manager. For example, store the secrets in Hashicorp Vault or 1password, and then use terraform to sync them to AWS and GCP.